# Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'

Tags: android, build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This strange behavior is happenning with my build application.

The strange is that this com.nineoldandroids is a jar that is from android resource libraries.

I have tried to delete build source and recompile again without luck.

My buildgradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            // enable crashlytics where you need
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library_refreshaction_appcompat')
    compile project(':EnhancedListView')
    compile project(':library_numberpicker')
    compile project(':materialDesign')
    compile project(':library_typeface')
    compile project(':library_updatechecker')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.7.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/BixolonPrinter.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/core-3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/VposAPI.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master')
}
```

Error Log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/Marcus/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/21.0.2/dx --dex --output /Users/Marcus/Workspace/android-pdv/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/library-2.4.0-c0bb3fabf202a58f481b22d99eb3ba9b89fd232d.jar /Users/Marcus/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nineoldandroids/library/2.4.0/e9b63380f3a242dbdbf103a2355ad7e43bad17cb/library-2.4.0.jar
  Error Code:
    139
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294663/cannot-build-android-project-using-android-studio-gradle-1-7 - error 139 seems to mean ["Segmentation Fault"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600683/995891), in your case in `dx` which is kind of bad because that's not supposed to happen. Try running the command it fails to manually from a console and see if you can see more of an error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As linked by @zapl [Cannot build android project using Android Studio - Gradle 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294663/cannot-build-android-project-using-android-studio-gradle-1-7), it is a strange behaviour that doesn't have only one way to solve it, as related by this post.

I couldn't say exactly what I did to solve it, because I tried many things until it disappeared.

But as said in the post, this is the way:

- Malformed Resources (Missing attributes, wrong tags, etc...)
- +id in Styles
- Duplicated resources / libraries
- Declare-Style able missing name
- Resource miss-match, try to use different AAPT versions.

Unknown, like mine. So it would be useful to:

1. Find a way to identify the real cause of this error
2. Wait for an update to AAPT that returns some error message
3. Write a list of possible common causes.

Comment: Nailed it! Duplicated libraries...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was fixed simply by restarting Android Studio.

I can only guess at the cause, but I think it happened because I launched my app while my emulator was still booting up.

Comment: Searched for half an hour until I found this hint ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have build-tools 21.0.2 installed but you are using 20.0.0 in your gradle buildTootlsVersion
Also you have defined `repositories` twice and you need it only in the first gradle block.

Try changing the build tools version.

Comment: I already set build-tools 21.0.2 , I just tried with many others and still the same bug, it sometimes says that the problem is with another library jar