# lmdb.open Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, lmdb

When I use python package LMDB to create a database, I got an error like this:
Here is the code caused the erro:

```
import lmbd
db_labels = lmdb.open(lmdb_label_name, map_size=1e1)
```

Actually, originally, the map_size is 1e12, some answers from here said maybe it is because of the memory run out, so I made it quite small, but still get the same error when I call LMDB package.

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

There is a poster to explain this, but he does not give me the solution:
 [Counter exit code 139 when running, but gdb make it through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600296/counter-exit-code-139-when-running-but-gdb-make-it-through)

Here is some other info for my OS:
OS, Mac OS X 10.11.6
Python: anaconda2 python2.7
LMDB version: `python -c "import lmdb;print lmdb.__version__"`, got 0.92.

Really hope someone can help me:)
Thanks in advance
Bonne journée

Comment: And for a reminder, I tried the older version of LMDB(0,89) on my Ubuntu14.04, and there is no errors, but I installed older version on my Mac, it does not work, any idea?